# ruby uninitialized constant in child class

Tags: ruby, constants

I keep getting this error:
uninitialized constant A::MYCONST
my code looks like

```
class A
  MYCONST = "myconst"
end

class B < A
 TEST = A::MYCONST
end
```

Comment: This code doesn't give me any error. A::MYCONST is defined as expected. Which ruby version do you use? Are you sure your `class A` is defined before?

Comment: If you still have error, give us the full code and error stack

Answer (score 0):

```
p RUBY_VERSION
class A
  MYCONST = "myconst"
end

class B < A
 p TEST = A::MYCONST
 p defined? TEST
end
```

***Output:***

```
"2.0.0"
"myconst"
"constant"
```

Answer (score 0):

Interpreter complains because it expects `B::A::MYCONST`.

Inside class B, the const defined in line2 can be referred by either `::A::MYCONST` or just `MYCONST`.